# Updating BLOB Image from the database

Tags: php, mysql, forms, blob, edit

I am having trouble updating a picture from MySQL, I used BLOB to store pictures but i can't update them. I can Create(upload) a pic, i can also Read(display) it, how ever i don't know how to Update it.

Here are my codes for the updating.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$con=@mysql_connect("localhost","root","12148qx3er");
$dbcheck = mysql_select_db("buybranded");
    if (!$dbcheck) {
        echo mysql_error();
    }
$itemid = $_GET['id'];
$image = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['prod_pic']['tmp_name']));
$sql = "UPDATE `inventory` SET
prod_brand = '$_POST[prod_brand]',
prod_name = '$_POST[prod_name]',
prod_category = '$_POST[prod_category]',
prod_price = '$_POST[prod_price]',
prod_desc = '$_POST[prod_desc]',
prod_quantity = '$_POST[prod_quantity]','{$image}', WHERE prod_id=$itemid";
if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error($con));
  }
header('refresh: 0;url=inventory.php');
$message = "Product Successfully Updated";
echo("<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>");
?>
```

and a follow up question, when I press update without a new file, it says file_get_contents() cannot be empty. Maybe my codes are wrong, i just need to update the entry whenever needed. i can update forms but not the pics.

here are the full update_inv.php codes

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Edit a Product</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="cms.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.autocomplete.js"></script>
    <script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#prod_brand").autocomplete("prod_brand_auto_complete.php", {
            selectFirst: true
      });
     });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
  <style>
button {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}
a{
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

</style>


<?php
session_start();
  $conn = @mysql_connect("localhost","root","12148qx3er");
  $db = @mysql_select_db("buybranded");
$itemid = $_GET['id'];
$qry = "SELECT * FROM inventory where prod_id = ".$itemid;
mysql_set_charset("UTF8");
$result = @mysql_query($qry);
if($result === FALSE) {
    die(mysql_error()); // TODO: better error handling
}


echo "<div id='page-wrap'>
  <h1>Edit a Product</h1>";
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){

$prodbrand = $row['prod_brand'];
$prodname = $row['prod_name'];
$prodcategory = $row['prod_category'];
$prodprice = $row['prod_price'];
$prod_desc = $row['prod_desc'];
$prodpic = $row['prod_pic'];
$prodquantity = $row['prod_quantity'];

echo "<form enctype='multipart/form-data' method='post' action='updating_inv.php?id=$itemid'>";
echo "<table>
      <tr>";
echo "<td><label for='prod_brand'>Product Brand:</label></td>
      <td><input name='prod_brand' id='prod_brand' type='text' maxlength='150' class='col1' placeholder='Auto Complete Form' value='$prodbrand'/></td>";

echo "<td><label for='prod_price'>Product Name:</label></td>
      <td><input name='prod_name' id='prod_name' type='text' maxlength='150' class='col1' value='$prodname'/></td>
      </tr>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td><label for='prod_price'>Product Price:</label></td>
      <td><input name='prod_price' id='prod_price' type='text' maxlength='10' class='col1' value='$prodprice'/></td>";
echo "<td> <label for='prod_category'>Category:</label></td>";

if($prodcategory=="Compression"){
echo "<td><label for='prod_category'>Category:</label>
      <select name='prod_category' class='col1'>$prodcategory
      <option>Select Category</option>
      <option selected>Compression</option>
      <option>Headwear</option>
      <option>Shorts</option>
      <option>Yoga</optino>
      <option>Swimming</option>
      <option>Fitness Training</option>
      <option>Water Bottles</option>
      <option>Sports Socks</option>
      <option>Sports Bags</option>
      <option>Protein Shaker</option>
      <option>Gloves</option>
      <option>Splash Guards</option>
      <option>Massagers</option>
      <option>Sun Blocks</option>
      <option>Sports Cleaners</option>
      </select></td>";
}
else if($prodcategory=="Headwear"){
 echo "<td><label for='prod_category'>Category:</label>
      <select name='prod_category' class='col1'>$prodcategory
      <option>Select Category</option>
      <option>Compression</option>
      <option selected>Headwear</option>
      <option>Shorts</option>
      <option>Yoga</optino>
      <option>Swimming</option>
      <option>Fitness Training</option>
      <option>Water Bottles</option>
      <option>Sports Socks</option>
      <option>Sports Bags</option>
      <option>Protein Shaker</option>
      <option>Gloves</option>
      <option>Splash Guards</option>
      <option>Massagers</option>
      <option>Sun Blocks</option>
      <option>Sports Cleaners</option>
      </select></td>"; 
}
else if($prodcategory=="Shorts"){
 echo "<td><label for='prod_category'>Category:</label>
      <select name='prod_category' class='col1'>$prodcategory
      <option>Select Category</option>
      <option>Compression</option>
      <option>Headwear</option>
      <option selected>Shorts</option>
      <option>Yoga</optino>
      <option>Swimming</option>
      <option>Fitness Training</option>
      <option>Water Bottles</option>
      <option>Sports Socks</option>
      <option>Sports Bags</option>
      <option>Protein Shaker</option>
      <option>Gloves</option>
      <option>Splash Guards</option>
      <option>Massagers</option>
      <option>Sun Blocks</option>
      <option>Sports Cleaners</option>
      </select></td>"; 
}
else if($prodcategory=="Yoga"){
 echo "<td><label for='prod_category'>Category:</label>
      <select name='prod_category' class='col1'>$prodcategory
      <option>Select Category</option>
      <option>Compression</option>
      <option>Headwear</option>
      <option>Shorts</option>
      <option selected>Yoga</optino>
      <option>Swimming</option>
      <option>Fitness Training</option>
      <option>Water Bottles</option>
      <option>Sports Socks</option>
      <option>Sports Bags</option>
      <option>Protein Shaker</option>
      <option>Gloves</option>
      <option>Splash Guards</option>
      <option>Massagers</option>
      <option>Sun Blocks</option>
      <option>Sports Cleaners</option>
      </select></td>"; 
}
else if($prodcategory=="Swimming"){
 echo "<td><label for='prod_category'>Category:</label>
      <select name='prod_category' class='col1'>$prodcategory
      <option>Select Category</option>
      <option>Compression</option>
      <option>Headwear</option>
      <option>Shorts</option>
      <option>Yoga</optino>
      <option selected>Swimming</option>
      <option>Fitness Training</option>
      <option>Water Bottles</option>
      <option>Sports Socks</option>
      <option>Sports Bags</option>
      <option>Protein Shaker</option>
      <option>Gloves</option>
      <option>Splash Guards</option>
      <option>Massagers</option>
      <option>Sun Blocks</option>
      <option>Sports Cleaners</option>
      </select></td>"; 
}
else if($prodcategory=="Fitness Training"){
 echo "<td><label for='prod_category'>Category:</label>
      <select name='prod_category' class='col1'>$prodcategory
      <option>Select Category</option>
      <option>Compression</option>
      <option>Headwear</option>
      <option>Shorts</option>
      <option>Yoga</optino>
      <option>Swimming</option>
      <option selected>Fitness Training</option>
      <option>Water Bottles</option>
      <option>Sports Socks</option>
      <option>Sports Bags</option>
      <option>Protein Shaker</option>
      <option>Gloves</option>
      <option>Splash Guards</option>
      <option>Massagers</option>
      <option>Sun Blocks</option>
      <option>Sports Cleaners</option>
      </select></td>"; 
}
else if($prodcategory=="Water Bottles"){
 echo "<td><label for='prod_category'>Category:</label>
      <select name='prod_category' class='col1'>$prodcategory
      <option>Select Category</option>
      <option>Compression</option>
      <option>Headwear</option>
      <option>Shorts</option>
      <option>Yoga</optino>
      <option>Swimming</option>
      <option>Fitness Training</option>
      <option selected>Water Bottles</option>
      <option>Sports Socks</option>
      <option>Sports Bags</option>
      <option>Protein Shaker</option>
      <option>Gloves</option>
      <option>Splash Guards</option>
      <option>Massagers</option>
      <option>Sun Blocks</option>
      <option>Sports Cleaners</option>
      </select></td>"; 
}
else if($prodcategory=="Sports Socks"){
 echo "<td><label for='prod_category'>Category:</label>
      <select name='prod_category' class='col1'>$prodcategory
      <option>Select Category</option>
      <option>Compression</option>
      <option>Headwear</option>
      <option>Shorts</option>
      <option>Yoga</optino>
      <option>Swimming</option>
      <option>Fitness Training</option>
      <option>Water Bottles</option>
      <option selected>Sports Socks</option>
      <option>Sports Bags</option>
      <option>Protein Shaker</option>
      <option>Gloves</option>
      <option>Splash Guards</option>
      <option>Massagers</option>
      <option>Sun Blocks</option>
      <option>Sports Cleaners</option>
      </select></td>"; 
}
else if($prodcategory=="Sports Bags"){
 echo "<td><label for='prod_category'>Category:</label>
      <select name='prod_category' class='col1'>$prodcategory
      <option>Select Category</option>
      <option>Compression</option>
      <option>Headwear</option>
      <option>Shorts</option>
      <option>Yoga</optino>
      <option>Swimming</option>
      <option>Fitness Training</option>
      <option>Water Bottles</option>
      <option>Sports Socks</option>
      <option selected>Sports Bags</option>
      <option>Protein Shaker</option>
      <option>Gloves</option>
      <option>Splash Guards</option>
      <option>Massagers</option>
      <option>Sun Blocks</option>
      <option>Sports Cleaners</option>
      </select></td>"; 
}
else if($prodcategory=="Protein Shaker"){
 echo "<td><label for='prod_category'>Category:</label>
      <select name='prod_category' class='col1'>$prodcategory
      <option>Select Category</option>
      <option>Compression</option>
      <option>Headwear</option>
      <option>Shorts</option>
      <option>Yoga</optino>
      <option>Swimming</option>
      <option>Fitness Training</option>
      <option>Water Bottles</option>
      <option>Sports Socks</option>
      <option>Sports Bags</option>
      <option selected>Protein Shaker</option>
      <option>Gloves</option>
      <option>Splash Guards</option>
      <option>Massagers</option>
      <option>Sun Blocks</option>
      <option>Sports Cleaners</option>
      </select></td>"; 
}
else if($prodcategory=="Gloves"){
 echo "<td><label for='prod_category'>Category:</label>
      <select name='prod_category' class='col1'>$prodcategory
      <option>Select Category</option>
      <option>Compression</option>
      <option>Headwear</option>
      <option>Shorts</option>
      <option>Yoga</optino>
      <option>Swimming</option>
      <option>Fitness Training</option>
      <option>Water Bottles</option>
      <option>Sports Socks</option>
      <option>Sports Bags</option>
      <option>Protein Shaker</option>
      <option selected>Gloves</option>
      <option>Splash Guards</option>
      <option>Massagers</option>
      <option>Sun Blocks</option>
      <option>Sports Cleaners</option>
      </select></td>"; 
}
else if($prodcategory=="Splash Guards"){
 echo "<td><label for='prod_category'>Category:</label>
      <select name='prod_category' class='col1'>$prodcategory
      <option>Select Category</option>
      <option>Compression</option>
      <option>Headwear</option>
      <option>Shorts</option>
      <option>Yoga</optino>
      <option>Swimming</option>
      <option>Fitness Training</option>
      <option>Water Bottles</option>
      <option>Sports Socks</option>
      <option>Sports Bags</option>
      <option>Protein Shaker</option>
      <option>Gloves</option>
      <option selected>Splash Guards</option>
      <option>Massagers</option>
      <option>Sun Blocks</option>
      <option>Sports Cleaners</option>
      </select></td>"; 
}
else if($prodcategory=="Massagers"){
 echo "<td><label for='prod_category'>Category:</label>
      <select name='prod_category' class='col1'>$prodcategory
      <option>Select Category</option>
      <option>Compression</option>
      <option>Headwear</option>
      <option>Shorts</option>
      <option>Yoga</optino>
      <option>Swimming</option>
      <option>Fitness Training</option>
      <option>Water Bottles</option>
      <option>Sports Socks</option>
      <option>Sports Bags</option>
      <option>Protein Shaker</option>
      <option>Gloves</option>
      <option>Splash Guards</option>
      <option selected>Massagers</option>
      <option>Sun Blocks</option>
      <option>Sports Cleaners</option>
      </select></td>"; 
}
else if($prodcategory=="Sun Blocks"){
 echo "<td><label for='prod_category'>Category:</label>
      <select name='prod_category' class='col1'>$prodcategory
      <option>Select Category</option>
      <option>Compression</option>
      <option>Headwear</option>
      <option>Shorts</option>
      <option>Yoga</optino>
      <option>Swimming</option>
      <option>Fitness Training</option>
      <option>Water Bottles</option>
      <option>Sports Socks</option>
      <option>Sports Bags</option>
      <option>Protein Shaker</option>
      <option>Gloves</option>
      <option>Splash Guards</option>
      <option>Massagers</option>
      <option selected>Sun Blocks</option>
      <option>Sports Cleaners</option>
      </select></td>"; 
}
else if($prodcategory=="Sports Cleaners"){
 echo "<td><label for='prod_category'>Category:</label>
      <select name='prod_category' class='col1'>$prodcategory
      <option>Select Category</option>
      <option>Compression</option>
      <option>Headwear</option>
      <option>Shorts</option>
      <option>Yoga</optino>
      <option>Swimming</option>
      <option>Fitness Training</option>
      <option>Water Bottles</option>
      <option>Sports Socks</option>
      <option>Sports Bags</option>
      <option>Protein Shaker</option>
      <option>Gloves</option>
      <option>Splash Guards</option>
      <option>Massagers</option>
      <option>Sun Blocks</option>
      <option selected>Sports Cleaners</option>
      </select></td>"; 
}
  echo "</tr>";
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td><label for='prod_desc'>Description:</label></td>
        <td><textarea name='prod_desc' id='prod_desc' class='col2'>$prod_desc</textarea></td>";
  echo "<td></td><td><table><tr>";
  echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' . base64_encode( $row['prod_pic'] ) . '" width="100" border="1px"/><br>';
  echo "<td><label for='prod_pic'>Upload Image:</label><br><input type='file' name='prod_pic' class='col2' value=''/></td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td><label for='prod_quantity'>Quantity:</label><br><input name='prod_quantity' id='prod_quantity' type='text' maxlength='10' class='col2' placeholder='ex. 10' value='$prodquantity'/></td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td><form method='post'><button>Update this Entry!</button>";
  echo "<button><a href='javascript:history.back()'>Go back</a></button></td>"; 
  echo "</tr></table></td></table>";

  echo "</form>";






  }
  echo "</div>";
?>

    </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have an extra *trailing* comma `'{$image}',`<= in `prod_quantity = '$_POST[prod_quantity]','{$image}', WHERE prod_id=$itemid";` so do `prod_quantity = '$_POST[prod_quantity]','{$image}' WHERE prod_id=$itemid";` - that will break your query.

Comment: Okay i removed it, tried uploading a picture it says 

"Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''����\0JFIF\0\0\0\0\0\0��\0;CREATOR: gd-jpeg v1.0 (using IJG JPEG v62' at line 7"

whats the problem? @Fred-ii-

Comment: This code and this approach should never be used in real-world scanario

Comment: Well, that's a start. An error doesn't mean failure.

Comment: *Woah there cowboy;* what column is `$image` supposed to be updated in?

Comment: I know, I just need these for a school project. I dont need it to be mysql injection safe. haha.@bad_boy

Comment: *Plus,* does your form contain `enctype='multipart/form-data'` and `method="post"`?

Comment: {image} should be inside the "prod_pic" column in the database.  ill update the codes in my question even if it's long

Comment: @Fred-ii- i updated the question and yes i have the enctype and method="post"

Comment: Try `prod_quantity = '$_POST[prod_quantity]', prod_pic = '{$image}' WHERE prod_id=$itemid";` you forgot to include the column `prod_pic`.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Well that did the job done. thanks!! however there is one more thing. how do i fix the error that says file_get_contents() cannot be empty when i update it without uploading a new pic. because sometimes i just need to upload the text in the forms.

Comment: Try `$image = file_get_contents($_FILES['prod_pic']['tmp_name']);`

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). Enjoy having your server pwn3d.

Comment: @MarcB True, yet [`OP states...`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25206961/updating-blob-image-from-the-database#comment39257851_25206961)

Comment: Sadly it didn't work @Fred-ii-

Comment: and a follow up question is that when i save it without uploading anything it removes the previous picture stored in the database. @Fred-ii-

Comment: Then you'll need to set a conditional statement for it. As for the `file_get_contents() cannot be empty` error, I don't know what it could be. I don't use uploading scripts in DB. I guess I could Google it, but I don't have time and to test etc. I've already solved the biggest problem.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Sure sure. THanks! Ill just ask another question if i can't google it. thanks for helping out!

Comment: `prod_quantity = '$_POST[prod_quantity]','{$image}', WHERE prod_i...`last comma is unnecessary. but probably its not causing the problem.